# Find the point where Johnny enters the pond

Tags: functions, curves

Johnny is in point (2,0) and walks to point (-2,0).On his way there’s a pond within the curve $\big|x\big|+\big|y\big|=1$. He walks 5 km/h outside the pond and $\frac{5\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{2}}$ km/h within the pond. In which point does he enter the pond, or should he walk around?

I don't know where to start. Does anyone have some tips?

Comment: Compute the time spent if he walks through the pond, or if he walks around, and compare. You know the speed, and you know the shape. In a medium with constant speed, the shortest path between two points is a straight line.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. But how do I find the lenght of the sides to the pond? I'm struggling a bit there.

Comment: The curve $|x|+|y|=1$ is a square, with vertices on the coordinate axes. Does that help?

Comment: Ohhh, of course! Sorry, I should have thought about that!! Thank you!

Comment: Last remark: be aware that Johnny might enter the pond and get out at an arbitrary point on the curve.

Comment: I found out that if he walks around, it will take him 0.96 hours, and if he walks in a straight line from (2,0) it will take him 0.91 hours. But the last remarke you made, how do I find out if he should enter the pond from an arbitrary point or not? Should I make a function of some sort?

Comment: Probably. But there is an ambiguity in the problem: is Johnny allowed to go straing to a point on the square, or does he have to walk first on the horizontal line till hitting the square? In the former case, then walking around takes only $0.8944$ hours, but it's still better to walk through from abscissa $1/2$ to $-1/2$ (I get $0.8854$ hours). You will have to write the time spent as a function of both entering and leaving, and minimize (check first order conditions, solve, and check that it's indeed a minimum).

Comment: Ohh, okay. I'm sorry for asking so much. But how do I make such a function? Because I can't see how I should do that, because then i need to make a function that take into consideration both that he can walk outside the square and inside the pond.

Comment: Choose the points where here enters and where he leaves the pond. That's two arbitrary numbers (the abscissa is enough, because of symmetry you can take $y\ge0$). You get a function $f$ of these abscissas $x_1,x_2$: join points with straight lines, compute the euclidian distance and divide each length by the speed to get the duration. Then differentiate and solve $\partial f/\partial x_1=0$ and $\partial f/\partial x_2=0$.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. I will try this!

Comment: I still a bit confused about making the function of the abcissas. The euclidian distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$ will be $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(f(x_1)-f(x_2))^2}$? And then I should divide by speed. But I have to unknows, so I don't how to solve the equation for 0. And what does the notation you use at the end mean?